Linux APRS to ethernet+LoRa service
I am thinking about creating an APRS igate using an ethernet-to-lora transciever, something like this
Before I reinvent the wheel, has someone already create a Linux service which does this?  (I don't want to use an ESP32 board, since this transceiver will do other things)

For anyone not familiar with the subject matter, many hams are already running APRS on 433MHz using small ESP32 based LoRa transceivers.  So the C/C++ software is already written, but is designed around the Arduino/ESP libraries.  I'm looking for something Linux specific.

hi! LoRA devices generally work in bands that are not amateur radio bands. How are you going to address this?

and, how do you get APRS into Modbus? It seems to me to be an extremely convoluted solution to APRS->APRS receiver->Linux Computer-> modbus packets containing APRS data -> Modbus Ethernet-to-LoRA transmitter

LoRa devices are available in many bands, including 433MHz and 915MHz.  Since this is unencrypted data I can legally use devices which operate in any ISM band, but I have chosen 433 since thats what other APRS+loRa devices are using.   I'm not sure I need modbus because these gateways can use MQTT out of the box, and I could populate the payload through an open source MQTT server.  But that's getting a bit far off track.  I'm just asking if someone has already done this.

thing is, still, why the PC->Network->network-to-lora gateway solution instead of a PC-attached LoRA card? I don't think anyone has done this, because it contains one superfluous complex component (it's of course impossible to know whether someone else has done this, but this is my guess)

The lora transceiver needs to be up a tall tower (too much power loss on coax).  So the PC needs to be seperate from the transceiver.

that feels like very important information! But since that device you picked up doesn't do PoE, either, and getting power there is the limiting factor for cabling here, you'd probably still be better off with a Linux single-board computer and a simple serially-attached LoRA transceiver; however, I now understand where you're coming from!

@TSG those devices still aren't generic "ethernet to LoRa" devices. They speak Modbus RTU on the radio side. And the "APRS over LoRa" protocol that hams use (when they do such a thing) isn't Modbus RTU. You want a completely different device. There are a million little ESP32 boards with SX1262s on them these days that could be programmed to do what you need.

@hobbs-KC2G: I thought about putting an ESP32 up the tower, but I'm actually hoping to (eventually) use the same transceiver for Meshtastic and APRS...all the MCU firmwares are single purpose.  I know 2 little heltec boards are cheap and easy to put up the tower, but I want to hack

@TSG well if you want to hack, that firmware is open-source. You can add "send APRS message" and "received APRS message" definitions to the protobuf, and add handlers for them in the code. Of course, it would be quite a lot easier to write a firmware for the same hardware that only does APRS, and use two devices, which would also allow two independent frequencies.
